# Using Arduino-UNO to control LED pins Greater than the Number of I/O Pins

Tags: arduino, led

Our class have been given a project to create a miniature of our department building. It will have 11 laboratory rooms, 1 server room, 1 faculty room. Each laboratory room will contain 18 pc's, each one represented by an LED. Server and faculty room will each have 3 LED.

Now each group of 3 LED's must be controlled individually using a computer program. So that's 68 groups of LED that needs individual control.

We are planning to use an Arduino UNO which have only 13 I/O pins. Is there any way to use those 13 I/O pins for 68 separate controls?

The deadline is near and we're in quite a pinch. Any answer will be tremendously appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basicaly two approaches, which might be combined: I/O extension, and multiplexing.

There are chips that are connected to your Arduino using a few pins (2 or 3), and that can provide more IO pins. Examples are 74HC595 shift register (requires 3 pins, provides 8 output pins, can be chained) and the MCP23017 I/O expander (requires 2 pins, provides 16 I/O pins, 8 such chips can share these two pins).

Multiplexing means that your split your I/O pins in rows and columns, let's say 6 rows and 7 columns, and you put a LED on each row/column crosspoint. By manipulating the row and column piuns, you can selectively light up one LED (or a row of LEDs, or a column of LEDs). Do this fast, and the human eye will get the impression that all LEDs are on. This will give you control over up to 42 LEds.

There is an advanced trick called Charlieplexing which allows you to control N * (N - 1 ) LEDs with N pins. I have used this for 12 LEDs (4 pins0, but I am not sure it works well enough for larger N.

What you choose is up to you. Personally I would consider either freeing up more Arduino pins and using the pins directly in a matrix, or using MCP23017's.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [NeoPixels](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/overview)!

You can easily control 68 ([or 1,000+!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-lR19_kigs)))  NeoPixels from a single Arduino IO pin.

They come in on a roll and you can cut off how ever many you need to put in each place using scissors...

[image]

...or you can buy them individually...

[image]

There is only one data line that goes into each pixel, then out the other side and on to the next neopixel so you daisy chain them together rather than having a wire for each LED in your setup. This will make your wiring job very easy.

There are lots of Arduino libraries available for controlling the pixels, so you will have a high level interface that let you get down to actually turning the pixels on and off almost immediately.

Comment: For the number of LEDs involved, I think this is an excellent suggestion. In fact, more generically: any addressable LED array, available from many suppliers in different form factors (strips, strings, individual units) and using a range of chips (Neopixel, WS2801, WS2811, WS2812B, LPD8806, TM1809..). I'd recommend the FastLED library (http://fastled.io/) - has worked a treat for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options, actually.

You could use some specific chips, try to search for "i2c led driver" or something like that. You hook as many drivers as needed to the same i2c line and boom, you virtually drive *a lot* of leds.

But there's also [multiplexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexed_display). You arrange your leds in a square matrix and turn on them one at a time, but that grants you control over 42 LEDs. But you can hook your LEDs in pairs and drive up to 84 LEDs, and that should be enough. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing#Complementary_drive). To turn on a LED you will need to tie the colum high, the row low, and al other columns and rows should be high Z. To turn on its complement you will need to tie the column low and the row high.

This last tecnique seems very appealing but:

- you will need to do an *awful lot* of wiring
- the maximum duty cycle is 1/68 that *can* be low
- assuming you want an average 1mA in each LED you are asking 68mA to the micro, that *can* be high

If the project is only about proof of concept go with the second option, do some math about current duty cycle and so on and you don't get the wiring part. I'd say go with the second because it's smart, and that's what I'd reward if I were your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Use 9 8-bit serial shift registers connected serially. You'll only need to provide power, ground, clock in, data in. (4 pins total, 2 I/O pins). These are capable of being daisy chained so that you can connect serial out to the serial in of the next shift register, and so on.

This article specifically for arduino outlines what needs to be done. 
http://arduino.cc/en/tutorial/ShiftOut

For parts, you can usually get these from Digikey (www.digikey.com) or mouser. 
In your arduino app, you will just need to know what the pattern will be to serially shift the data into LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [LED driver](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5926-q1.pdf)

16 bits wide, so you'll only need five of them, outputs are constant current, and each output can sink 120 mA.

Plus, the thing is a shift register with an output latch, so you'll only need to use 3 of your Arduino's I/Os to talk to it.